# Is there any way to delete the vault states in corda node in dev mode?

Tags: blockchain, corda

When we working with Corda, we are doing lots of testing.

When we need to make the clean slate, every time we are cleaning up the build folder, taking the new build for the nodes.

Is there any simple way to avoid the rebuilding of the nodes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Corda testing frameworks:

1. The contract testing framework, for testing contract execution ([docs](https://docs.corda.net/api-testing.html#contract-testing), [example](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/java-source/src/test/java/com/example/contract/IOUContractTests.java))
2. The flow testing framework, for testing flow execution ([docs](https://docs.corda.net/api-testing.html#flow-testing), [example](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/java-source/src/test/java/com/example/flow/IOUFlowTests.java))
3. The node driver, for integration testing ([example](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/java-source/src/integrationTest/java/com/example/DriverBasedTests.java))

These allow you to test your CorDapp without having to start any nodes.

Comment: The links are helpful, but don't answer the actual question. How do you delete all ContractStates in a node?